# How to add time element in our Pinescript

Tags: pine-script

I want to add a time element to my data, for example:

1. (Condition A) - (Condition B) > 1

(Description: Condition A is read instantly from the diagram. But **I want condition B to be *calculated only at the end of each candle closure*, not momentarily**)

2. I will receive a warning **if the difference between the two numbers is above 1 for *more than 20 seconds.* How can I add the element of time to this phrase?**

condition = rsi-T > 1

alertcondition(condition, title='good time', message='good!')

Please guide me through both situations

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, you cannot time the duration of conditions in the realtime bar because of the rollback process. See [Can I time the duration of a condition?](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#can-i-time-the-duration-of-a-condition) from our FAQ.

You can only use something like `timenow - time` to calculate the time elapsed since the beginning of the realtime bar.

An enhancement to allow for this is planned and in our top priorities. It should see the light of day in the medium-term future, but there is no ETA yet.

> **Disclosure**: the link in this answer points to a PineCoders FAQ entry.
> I am a member of the PineCoders community and I most probably wrote that FAQ entry. PineCoders is a TradingView-supported group of volunteer Pine coders and PineCoders' website is strictly educational. Neither TradingView nor PineCoders benefits financially from sending traffic to pinecoders.com, and the site contains no affiliate/referral links.

Comment: What about the first condition : (Condition A) - (Condition B) > 1
(Description: Condition A is read instantly from the diagram. But I want condition B to be calculated only at the end of each candle closure, not momentarily). Is this also not possible?

Comment: On historical bars, Pine scripts only execute on the bar's close, so no need for anything special code there. In the realtime bar it's a different story, as the usrman page on the [execution model](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html) explains. You can add `barstate.isconfirmed` to restrict your condition to being true only on the close of the realtime bar.

Comment: I read the article, but how it can help me, I will explain what I want with an example:
I want to define a script to gives me, buy signal when RSI is lower 30 but price crosses up BB' lower band, 

rsi < 30 and price > lower BB (both conditions read in real time)

and gives me a signal for sell, when last closed RSI value is greater than 30 and price is above BB lower band.

rsi > 30 and price > lower BB (script should read rsi from last historical candle but script should read BB in real time)

Comment: let's think we are on 15 min time frame and the time is 15:15:00 so last candle closes and new candle opens. I have two indicator RSI and BB. RSI = 23.8 and price is below BB lower limit. at 15:18:21 price crosses up BB lower limit ==> I receive a signal for buy opportunity, at 15:21:34 price is above BB' lower band and RSI = 40. I do not want to receive, sell's signal at 15:21:34, so, script should use RSI value at 15:15:00 but detect price situation between BB,s bands at 15:21:34, otherwise if script calculates the RSI at 15:21:34 I will receive a sell signal, and it is not my desire.

Comment: how I can define this for script to use RSI value in last closed candle (last historical value) instead of real value.

Comment: `rsi(close, 14)[1]`

Comment: Thanks Piecoders-LucF, It works, :) can you tell me where I can find more relative information about this section?

Comment: See the usrman on the [History reference operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-referencing-operator) and [series](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Type_system.html#series).